# How to find out which Service Pack is installed on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

How can I find out which Service Pack is installed on my copy of SQL Server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From TechNet: [Determining which version and edition of SQL Server Database Engine is running](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Determining-which-version-af0f16f6)

```
-- SQL Server 2000/2005
SELECT  SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')

-- SQL Server 6.5/7.0
SELECT @@VERSION
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Select @@Version
```

> Ex: My machine has the following one installed.
>
> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (Intel X86) Apr 2
>   2010 15:53:02 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition
>   on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)